# Can a managed package alter the page layout of Lead Page?

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, page-layout, leads

I have created a Visualforce page using `standardController="Lead"` and I  use this page in the page layout for Lead page .

I have create a managed package with this page and layout but I do not see the new lead page layout in my test org's lead details page.

How do I create a package such that once it is deployed, it can show my Visualforce page in the test org's lead page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FieldSet or Compact Layout to change that. 
User can easily change the FieldSet and Compact layout even in managed package as well.